# What are the risks of having a database with user ids outside an internal network?

Tags: security

If a company makes available its user ids in an external database, but not the passwords, and if this database gets hacked, how easier it becomes for the hackers to then brute force access to the internal network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't share your user ids with external application without masking. For example;

```
http://www.example.com/user/1/edit
http://www.example.com/user/2/edit
```

From external application user will see above urls. That means anyone from outside of the organization will be able to enumerate whole database like number of users, user ids and username match-up etc.

You can use http://hashids.org . It's generating short unique string from integers. With that way, external application will only see masked values rather than actual ids.

```
http://www.example.com/user/a8sf71/edit
http://www.example.com/user/d0nd1d/edit
```